# Why does my program not work properly when trying to directly set my variable to a random integer using Int.random()?

Tags: ios, swift

I am following an online tutorial and when trying to directly set my `randomBallNumber` variable to a random number between 1 and 4 using `randomBallNumber = Int.random(in: 0...4)`, my code doesn't work. However, when I first use `var randomBallNumber = 0` and then change its value to a random one inside of a function, it runs properly.

Works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let ballArray = ["ball1", "ball2", "ball3", "ball4", "ball5"]

    var randomBallNumber = 0

    func newBallImage() {
        ImageView.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[randomBallNumber])
        randomBallNumber = Int.random(in: 0...4)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newBallImage()
    }

    @IBAction func askButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        newBallImage()
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        newBallImage()
    }
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let ballArray = ["ball1", "ball2", "ball3", "ball4", "ball5"]

    var randomBallNumber = Int.random(in: 0...4)

    func newBallImage() {
        ImageView.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[randomBallNumber])
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newBallImage()
    }

    @IBAction func askButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        newBallImage()
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        newBallImage()
    }
}
```

The only console error I am getting is:

> 2019-07-10 07:22:45.328092+0300 8BallPool[86631:3716368] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

and it shows for both variants.

The expected result would be for the image to change when the Ask! button is pressed which it doesn't when using the second piece of code.

Comment: Your 2nd set of code doesn't work because you only ever call `Int.random` once when initializing the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var randomBallNumber = Int.random(in: 0...4)
```

This will be initialized once, and after that the value of `randomBallNumber` will not change unless you change it again. 
So instead of making it as a global variable better make a function like:

```
func getRandomNumber() -> Int {
   return Int.random(in: 0...4)
}
```

And call it wherever you need the `randomBallNumber`, like:

```
ImageView.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[getRandomNumber()])
```

**Note:** Always declare variable and outlet names in `camelCase`, where the first character should be small. Here your `ImageView` is a very wrong name, instead name it something like `randomBallImageView`.

Comment: or `var randomBallNumber: Int { return Int.random(in: 0...4) }` depending on your preference ;)

Comment: Even better: `var randomBall: String { return ballArray.randomElement() }`.